# open pdf file stored in devonthink via link in pdf generated by latex

Tags: links, macos

I am writing my notes in latex, and have to open a reference pdf stored in devonthink, which has an option of creating a link like x-devonthink-item://2A4BA600-D5CB-4414-852F-5FC596703941  Usually it opens when I add it in obsidian with file tag. But not aware how to get it accessed in pdf generated by latex.

> What I want is to create a link in latex generated pdf, which when
> clicked should open the pdf in devonthink on my Mac.

Comment: it have no idea what this is and if your pdf viewer can handle that, but would try a file or a launch link, so `\href{file:x-devonthink-item://2A4BA600-D5CB-4414-852F-5FC596703941}{xx}` or `\href{run:x-devonthink-item://2A4BA600-D5CB-4414-852F-5FC596703941}{xx}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Neither of those will work.

Comment: @AlanMunn well I assumed that the normal \href didn't work and so suggested the other options ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adding the link using `\href` works.  Remember to load `hyperref` last in your list of packages unless another package specifically tells you to load it before that package.

Whether the link works depends on your PDF viewer. The following document works for me with Skim and Adobe Reader, but not Preview.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{x-devonthink-item://9DBEDEA0-3F7A-4DA5-8EB7-1FB5E0658494}{My Devonthink document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks a ton for your time and help!